# check visibility of IE save dialog box using Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Currently, in my web application, I want to automatically save the generated excel reports on button click.

Issue:-  I am not able to identify the visibility of IE save dialog box using Robot Class

Logic used to save IE file  which is working successfully to save  when alert is prompted

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.setAutoDelay(5000);
Thread.sleep(3000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
Thread.sleep(1000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
```

How to check the visibility of save dialog box in IE 11 browser also in Firefox?

I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540418/java-selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-check-if-the-file-download-dialog-box-is-vi) for the solution but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Robot class does not provide possibility to detect if dialog is visible or not. Just put appropriate delays and clicks on buttons.

Comment: Thanks, @Sanja Paskova. My logic clicks on the button whereas due to some application error it is not generating the IE browser dialog box. Now how to check the browser dialog box?

Comment: Report the bug and wait issue to be resolved. As I'm aware there is no possibility to know if the dialog is opened or not with current possibilities of selenium.